# Replacing VirtualPrintEngine with JsPDF

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic, jspdf

*Keep in mind :*
This is my first question on StackOverflow.
The web app is a software package that the company modified for their needs.
The part on is using Virtual Print Engine from IDEAL Software (VPE).
Values were modified for this post

**Issue**
The main issue is that VPE uses ActiveX Control and we're trying to ditch Internet Explorer.
The process is to create PDF the size of the stickers they use for shipping.

*Try to stay with me while I try to explain how the generatePDF.asp is called :*

- The user click on a button in the page report_up.asp which post a request to report_pr.asp
- report_pr.asp then process the post and calls report.asp
- generatePDF.asp generates the PDF, sends it straight to the selected printer

So the whole process is hidden from the dev tool from the browser (except on IE)

Here's a sample of the original code. As you might notice, I also juggle with VBScript.
**Edited to add more code**

```
        <%@ LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT %>
    <%Option Explicit%>
    <!-- #Include virtual="\SOFTinit.asp" -->
    <!-- #Include virtual="\reportfunction.asp" -->
    <%
    DIM rssql,vstorename,vparam,vserialnoparam,vprintsection,vpiecestock,vnbretiquettes,vversion
    DIM vwonbr,vdescr,vserialno,vshortserialno,vname,vtransport,vexpedition,vliste,vpoprojet,vzone
    DIM vsoustraitance,vitemserialid,vitemid,vcodemecinov,vwoid,vshipbarcodeid,vpono,vprintername,vlabelexpedition
    DIM visrack,vcustname,vcustid,vcodeboite,vzonerack,vcodebarre,vtempid
    DIM i

    vversion="v1.0"
    vstorename = "IN_RPT.ProductsBarCode_sp"
    vshipbarcodeid = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fshipbarcodeid")))
    vtempid = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("ftempid")))
    IF visrack = 0 THEN
      vserialnoparam = REQ("fnoserie")
    END IF
    vsoustraitance = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fsoustraitance")))
    vitemserialid  = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fitemserialid")))
    vitemid        = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fitemid")))
    vwoid          = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fwoid")))
    visrack        = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("frack")))

    IF visrack <> 0 THEN

    '   vcustid    = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fcustid")))
      vcodeboite = TRIM(REQ("fcodeboite"))

    '  sql = "SELECT Name,fob FROM customers WHERE custid = " & vcustid
    '  SET RSSQL = CONN.EXECUTE(SQL)
    '   IF NOT RSSQL.EOF THEN
    '    vcustname = TRIM(RSSQL("Name"))
    '    vzonerack = TRIM(RSSQL("fob"))
    '   END IF
    '  RSSQL.CLOSE
    '  SET RSSQL = NOTHING

      sql = "SELECT codemecinov,shipbarcodeid FROM shipbarcode WHERE  isactive=1 AND cieid= "& gcieid &" AND codeboite = '" & vcodeboite & "' "
      SET RSSQL = CONN.EXECUTE(SQL)
        IF NOT RSSQL.EOF THEN
        'vcodebarre = TRIM(RSSQL("codemecinov"))
        vshipbarcodeid =RSSQL("shipbarcodeid")
        END IF
      RSSQL.CLOSE
      SET RSSQL = NOTHING
        response.write vshipbarcodeid
        response.write sql
    END IF


    IF vshipbarcodeid <> 0 Then
        SQL = "SELECT shipbarcode.codebarre as serialno,shipbarcode.itemserialid,shipbarcode.woid,shipbarcode.itemid,shipbarcode.soustraitance,SOTOMECINOVID FROM shipbarcode " &_
                    " LEFT JOIN sotomecinov ON sotomecinov.serialno = shipbarcode.codebarre " &_
                    " WHERE shipbarcodeid = " & vshipbarcodeid
        SET RSSQL = CONN.EXECUTE(SQL)
        IF NOT RSSQL.EOF THEN
            vserialnoparam = RSSQL("SOTOMECINOVID")
            vitemserialid = CDBL(RSSQL("itemserialid"))
            vitemid = CDBL(RSSQL("itemid"))
            vsoustraitance = SOFT.FNBOOLEAN(RSSQL("soustraitance"))
            vwoid = CDBL(RSSQL("woid"))
            'BOITE DE PRODUCTION
            IF vwoid <> 0  Then
                vserialnoparam = rssql("serialno")
            END IF
            IF vsoustraitance = 1 Then
                vserialnoparam = rssql("serialno")
            END IF
        END IF
    END IF

    IF visrack = 0 THEN
      vprintsection  = REQ("fprintsection")
    END IF
    vnbretiquettes = SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("fnbrcopy"))
    IF vnbretiquettes = 0 THEN
        vnbretiquettes = 1
    END IF
    vpiecestock   = CDBL(SOFT.IFEMPTY(REQ("forshipping")))

    vprintername = ""
    SQL = "SELECT zprinter.name as printername FROM zprinter " &_
                " INNER JOIN zprinteruser ON zprinteruser.userid =  " & guserid &_
                " WHERE (zprinteruser.menuid = 2021 or zprinteruser.menuid = 2020) AND zprinter.printerid = zprinteruser.printerid "
    SET RSSQL =CONN.EXECUTE(SQL)
    IF NOT RSSQL.EOF Then
        vprintername = RSSQL("printername")
    END IF


    '****************************************************************************************************
    '*** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *SECTION HTML* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ***
    '****************************************************************************************************

    %>

    <html>
    <head>
      <title><%=getlabel("Codeboite",glangid)%></title>
      <META HTTP-EQUIV="pragma"  CONTENT="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
      <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>

    </head>
    <body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" bottommargin="0" rightmargin="0">
      <!-- #Include virtual="\VpeCtrl4.asp"-->

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">

        <% if vshipbarcodeid = 0 AND vpiecestock = 0 then %>
            window.parent.opener.focus();
        <% end if %>
      var vfont,vRender;

      VpeCtrl.CloseDoc();
      VpeCtrl.OpenDoc();
      VpeCtrl.UnitTransformation = VUNIT_FACTOR_MM10;
      VpeCtrl.DevPrintQuality    = 200;
      VpeCtrl.DevJobName         = 'etiquette';
      VpeCtrl.SaveFileName       = 'etiquette.pdf';
      VpeCtrl.FontName           = "Verdana";
      //VpeCtrl.PageFormat         = VPAPER_LETTER;
      VpeCtrl.BarcodeAlignment   = ALIGN_CENTER;
      VpeCtrl.BarcodeMainTextParms  = BCP_HIDE;
      VpeCtrl.BarcodeAutoChecksum   = 1;
      VpeCtrl.PageWidth  = 1050;
      VpeCtrl.PageHeight = 1270;

      VpeCtrl.ScalePercent       = 100;
      VpeCtrl.PageOrientation    = VORIENT_PORTRAIT;
      VpeCtrl.SetOutRect(10,10,VpeCtrl.PageWidth,VpeCtrl.PageHeight);

      <%

      IF visrack = 0 OR visrack = 1 THEN
            vparam = "@glangid="                & glangid &_
                       ",@gcieid="              & gcieid &_
                       ",@guserid="             & guserid &_
                     ",@fnoserie='"         & vserialnoparam & "'" &_
                     ",@fprintsection='"    & vprintsection & "'" &_
                     ",@piecestock="      & vpiecestock &_
                     ",@nbretiquettes=1"  &_
                     ",@soustraitance="     & vsoustraitance &_
                     ",@Itemserialid="      & vitemserialid  &_
                     ",@itemid="                    & vitemid &_
                     ",@woid="                    & vwoid
            IF vshipbarcodeid <> 0 THEN
                vparam = vparam &_
                                 ",@shipbarcodeid=" & vshipbarcodeid
            END IF
            IF vtempid <> 0 THEN
                vparam = vparam &_
                                 ",@tempid=" & vtempid
            END IF

            SQL = "EXEC " & vstorename & " " & vparam & ""
                    response.write "//" & sql
            'RESPONSE.END
            SET rssql = CONN.EXECUTE(SQL)
            IF rssql.eof THEN
                RESPONSE.END
            END IF
            DO WHILE NOT RSSQL.EOF
                FOR i = 1 to CDBL(RSSQL("copycount"))
                            IF i <> 1 tHEN %>
                                VpeCtrl.PageBreak();
                            <%
                            END IF
                vwonbr = RSSQL("wonbr")
                vdescr = RSSQL("descr")
                vserialno = RSSQL("serialno")
                vshortserialno = RSSQL("shortserialno")
                vname = RSSQL("name")
                vlabelexpedition = RSSQL("expeditionlabel")
                vexpedition = RSSQL("expedition")
                vtransport = RSSQL("transport")
                vliste = RSSQL("liste")
                vcodemecinov = RSSQL("codemecinov")
                vpono = RSSQL("po")
                IF ISNULL(vliste) THEN
                    vliste = ""
                END IF
                vpoprojet = RSSQL("project")
                vzone = RSSQL("zone")

                RESPONSE.WRITE "Before Header Loop"
                %>
                //HEADER
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 24;
                <%
                    IF LEN(vserialno) > 18 THEN
                        RESPONSE.WRITE "VpeCtrl.FontSize = 18;"
                    END IF
                %>
                <% IF vsoustraitance = 1 THEN %>
                    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(30,18,1025,VFREE,'[N B 72]<%=vserialno%>');
                <% ELSE %>
                    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(30,18,1025,VFREE,'[N B 72]<%=vshortserialno%>');
                <% END IF %>
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 12;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(40,105,1020,160,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vname)%>');
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 10;
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
                <% IF vsoustraitance = 0 THEN %>
                    VpeCtrl.FontSize = 9;
                    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(50,160,400,230,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vlabelexpedition)%>');
                    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(50,190,400,250,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vexpedition)%>');
                     VpeCtrl.FontSize = 10;
                <% END IF %>
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=0;
                VpeCtrl.BarCode(385, 160, 1005, 250, BCT_CODE128, '<%=vcodemecinov%>', '');
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=1;
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(60,250,500,300,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vtransport)%>');
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
                <% IF vsoustraitance = 1 THEN %>
                    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(450,250,1000,300,'[N B 72]<%=vshortserialno%>');
                <% ELSE %>
                    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(450,250,1000,300,'[N B 72]<%=vserialno%>');
                <% END IF %>

                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(60,300,1020,400,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vdescr)%>');
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(60,390,650,440,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vpoprojet)%>');
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_RIGHT;
                            VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(660,390,1000,440,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vpono)%>');
                //VpeCtrl.Vpeline(40,360,1020,360);
                            VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;

                //DÉTAIL
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=0;
                VpeCtrl.Rotation = 2700;
                VpeCtrl.BarCode(60, 440, 660, 520, BCT_CODE128, '<%=vcodemecinov%>', '');
                VpeCtrl.Rotation = 0;
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=1;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(200,450,1040,1030,'[N 72]<%=FNGuilJava2(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(vliste),VBCRLF,"\n"),CHR(13),"\n"), CHR(10),"\n"))%>');

                //FOOTER
                VpeCtrl.Picture(60,1070,250,1250,'<%=LocatePgm("sys/getlogo.asp",1)%>' + EncryptParams('?gsessionid=<%=gsessionid%>&cieid=<%=gcieid%>'));
                VpeCtrl.Picture(280,1070,480,1250,'<%=locatepgm("images/madeincanada.jpg",1)%>');
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(520,1140,750,VFREE,'<%=FNGETDATE(gCurrDate)%>');
                VpeCtrl.Pensize=5;
                VpeCtrl.Box(770,1070,1020,1250);
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 26;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(840,1110,1015,1250,'[N B 72]<%=vzone%>');
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 10;
                <%
                NEXT
             RSSQL.MOVENEXT

             IF NOT RSSQL.EOF THEN
                %>VpeCtrl.PageBreak();<%
             END IF

             LOOP

      ELSE%>
                //HEADER
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 24;
                <%
                  RESPONSE.WRITE "Before Header"
                    IF LEN(vserialno) > 18 THEN
                        RESPONSE.WRITE "VpeCtrl.FontSize = 18;"
                    END IF
                %>

                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(30,18,1025,VFREE,'[N B 72]<%=vcodeboite%>');

                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 12;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(40,105,1020,160,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vcustname)%>');
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 10;
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=0;
                VpeCtrl.BarCode(385, 160, 1005, 250, BCT_CODE128, '<%=vcodebarre%>', '');
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=1;
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(60,250,500,300,'[N B 72]<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(vtransport)%>');
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(450,250,1000,300,'[N B 72]<%=vcodeboite%>');

                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(60,300,1020,400,'[N B 72]<%="Rack"%>');
                VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_RIGHT;
                //VpeCtrl.Vpeline(40,360,1020,360);
                            VpeCtrl.TextAlignment = ALIGN_LEFT;

                //DÉTAIL
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=0;
                VpeCtrl.Rotation = 2700;
                VpeCtrl.BarCode(60, 440, 660, 520, BCT_CODE128, '<%=vcodebarre%>', '');
                VpeCtrl.Rotation = 0;
                VpeCtrl.PenSize=1;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(200,450,1040,1030,'[N 72]<%=FNGuilJava2(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(vliste),VBCRLF,"\n"),CHR(13),"\n"), CHR(10),"\n"))%>');

                //FOOTER
                VpeCtrl.Picture(60,1070,250,1250,'<%=LocatePgm("sys/getlogo.asp",1)%>' + EncryptParams('?gsessionid=<%=gsessionid%>&cieid=<%=gcieid%>'));
                VpeCtrl.Picture(280,1070,480,1250,'<%=locatepgm("images/madeincanada.jpg",1)%>');
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(520,1140,750,VFREE,'<%=FNGETDATE(gCurrDate)%>');
                VpeCtrl.Pensize=5;
                VpeCtrl.Box(770,1070,1020,1250);
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 26;
                VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(840,1110,1015,1250,'[N B 72]<%=vzonerack%>');
                VpeCtrl.FontSize = 10;
                <%
      END IF
      %>
        <%IF vshipbarcodeid <> 0 AND visrack = 0 THEN %>

            <% IF vprintername <> "" Then %>
                VpeCtrl.Preview();
                //VpeCtrl.Device = '<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(REPLACE(vprintername,"\","\\"))%>';
                //VpeCtrl.PrintDoc(false)
                //window.close()
            <% else %>
                    VpeCtrl.Preview();
            <%  END IF %>
        <% ELSE %>
            VpeCtrl.DevCopies = <%=vnbretiquettes%>;
            <% IF vprintername <> "" Then %>
              VpeCtrl.Device = '<%=SOFT.FNGUILJAVA2(REPLACE(vprintername,"\","\\"))%>';
            <% END IF %>
            //VpeCtrl.Preview();
            VpeCtrl.PrintDoc(false)
            window.close()
        <% END IF %>

    </SCRIPT>
    </body>
    </html>
    <%
    RSSQL.CLOSE
    SET RSSQL = NOTHING
    SOFT.DisconnectDB
    %>
```

I've made a whole .html to test how JsPdf worked and I was able to create the same exact replica of the one generated by VPE.
The function save(), ouput() and autoprint() works perfectly fine on my local HTML

Sample

```
    var doc = new jsPDF({
        orientation: 'p',
        unit: 'mm',
        format: [105, 125]
    });
    JsBarcode("#barcodeHorizontal", "00-000-000-00");
    JsBarcode("#barcodeVertical", "00-000-000-00", {
    displayValue: false
    });

    doc.addFont("Verdana", "Verdana", "Regular")
    doc.setFont("Verdana", "Regular");

    //HEADER
    doc.setFontSize(24);
    doc.text('Value', 5, 10);

    doc.setFontSize(12);
    doc.text('Value', 5, 15);

    doc.setFontSize(9);
    doc.text('Value :', 5, 19);
    doc.text('Value', 5, 22);
    doc.setFontSize(10);

    const barcodeHorizontal = document.querySelector("img#barcodeHorizontal");
    doc.addImage(barcodeHorizontal.src, "PNG", 48, 16, 55, 13, "");
    doc.text('Value', 5, 25);

    const barcodeVertical = document.querySelector("img#barcodeVertical");
    doc.addImage(barcodeVertical.src, "PNG", 2, 30, 60, 10, "", "NONE", -90);
    doc.text('Value', 8, 32)
    doc.text('Value', 8, 40)
    doc.text('Value', 70, 40)
```

**What I've tried**

- I've changed everything to use the JsPDf

```
    // VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(30,18,1025,VFREE,'[N B 72]<%=value%>');
    doc.text("value",3,2);
```

- I've tried to keep both version

```
    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(30,18,1025,VFREE,'[N B 72]<%=value%>');
    doc.text("value",3,2);
```

- Added console.log() to see if i'd stop at some point

```
    VpeCtrl.VpeWrite(30,18,1025,VFREE,'[N B 72]<%=value%>');
    doc.text("value",3,2);
    console.log("Error value");
```

- I've tried try/catch most of them to see if I was able to catch an error

```
    try {
        doc.text("value",3,2);
        console.log('<%=value%>');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error here");
    }
```

**Here is the result I get from multiple tries :**

Corrupted or not a PDF from :

```
    doc.save("sticker.pdf");
```

Empty window from :

```
    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

I still get no error from the try/catch and I see all my console.log()

**My unanswered questions so far**
- Could there be a conflict between multiples JQuery.js - Which I do not have control over
- Could there be a conflict with VBScript?
- Could there be a problem during the process described earlier?

I'm open to any suggestions, comments or to provide more details if needed!

**EDIT**

I've tried the simplest way possible and It didn't work! I'm starting to think I won't work since the process is made server-side

```
    var doc = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'p',
    unit: 'mm',
    format: [105, 127]

    doc.text("value",5,16);
    doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

Comment: I would focus all my efforts on the JsPDF approach and remove VPE-related code. This will make the question clearer. With JsPDF, I'd start simple, trying to get a "hello world" PDF to work and then re-introduce previous functionalities.

Comment: By the sound of things, the whole PDF generation process happens **on the server** which is where it should be then the result passed back as a server response. Not sure why you insist and trying to change it to generate client-side, what are your reasons for doing it?

Comment: @Étienne Laneville I was able to generate the whole PDF as it was before but I`ll try again with baby steps. Thank you

Comment: @Landymart I was asked to replace the old method because it was only supported on Internet Explorer and I chose JsPDF because it seemed reliable and easy to use! It also needed to be fast.

Comment: @mrALX That's my point the old method is a server-side render, what part of that process makes it *"only supported on Internet Explorer"*? From what I can see you have been very thorough with your explanation but have made a lot of assumptions so the useful information about what the issue is with the server-side render has been left out.

Comment: @Lankymart The VpeCtrl uses ActiveX if that answers your question. I'm currently looking for a solution with my coworker to bring, front-end, the information we need to use JsPDF

Comment: @mrASX it would help if you could [edit] the question to include `generatePDF.asp` so we have a better idea of how it generates the PDF.

Comment: @Lankymart I've edited the sample to include more code from generatePDF.asp

Comment: @mrALX right think I understand now `generatePDF.asp` doesn't generate the PDF server-side it's just a UI script to interact and pass data to the VPE ActiveX Control which is generating the PDF client-side but the process of how it does it will be completely locked down inside the ActiveX Control.

Comment: @mrALX personally when it comes to PDF generation I've not found a better COM library then [Persists.PDF](http://www.asppdf.com). Used it for years for generating all sorts of complex PDF layouts from a database, I would highly recommend it if you are stuck using Classic ASP. Avoids having to handle it all client-side and the server-side generated output can be returned as a PDF manipulated, printed, saved etc.

Comment: Relevant [How can I create a PDF file in classic ASP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/440905)

Comment: @Lankymart I'll check Persists.PDF but the only problem I see is that it requires a license and I'm not the one taking those decisions. Sadly the link in the Relevant Question for free options seems to be broken.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville actually if you look at the Classic ASP code you'll see that it doesn’t generate server-side. The ASP page is purely to populate a client-side ActiveX control using data from a database.

Comment: @mrALX because the industry moved on, Classic ASP is dead and should only be used to maintain old projects that haven't moved across to a newer technology.

Comment: @Lankymart I'm aware that the industry has moved on from Classic and yet here I am doing my internship and trying to improve a program that still uses it! Thanks for your help,  it's appreciated